# How to get the class name of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of divs...

```
<div class='happy person'><img src='#' /></div>
<div class='fat person'><img src='#' /></div>
<div class='joyous person'><img src='#' /></div>
<div class='grotesque person'><img src='#' /></div>
<div class='sad person'><img src='#' /></div>
```

that I have selected using...

```
var people = $('.person')
```

The results are stored in a class variable.
jQuery stores the results of this selection as an array of HTMLDivElements - which they are.

Later on, I want to be able to look at this array and make some decisions with respect to the class of each element. I have read up on a possible solution; but this fails since I am not dealing directly with a jQuery object.

How do I get the class names of these divs in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var people = $('.person');
$.each(people, function(index, el) {
    var _this = $(el);
    if (_this.hasClass('happy')) {
        alert('Happy!');
    } else if (_this.hasClass('fat')) {
        alert('Fat!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm not dealing directly with a jQuery object", as `$('.person')` returns a jQuery object, wrapped around an array of elements.

To get the class(es) of an element, just use `.attr('class')` on the jQuery object. Combine this with a `.map()` and you can create an array of only the class names for each element:

```
var classes = $('.person').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('class');
}).get();
```

This will produce the following array:

```
['happy person', 'fat person', ..., 'sad person']
```

Answer (score 1):

As taken from: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/91636-getting-class-name-string, this might be worth trying if you're not using jQuery.

```
function getClassName(obj) {
   if (typeof obj != "object" || obj === null) return false;
   return /(\w+)\(/.exec(obj.constructor.toString())[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div_attrs = node.attributes;
div_class = div_attrs.getNamedItem("class").value;
```

Comment: In `div_class`, the variable should be `div_attrs`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through them using pure JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
  var class = people[i].attr('class');
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
people.each(function()
{
  var class = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

You do know that having a class `fat person` is not having the class `fat person`? It's inheriting the CSS properties from both `fat` and `person`. If you need a class name like this, use underscores: `fat_person`.

Comment: thanks. I understand the inheritance of CSS classes. In your example, I will be lookinf for the class "fat" which should return the object with the classes "fat" and "person"

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the classes on an individual div, use the `.attr` function.

```
var classes = myDiv.attr('class');
```

This will return a space-separated list of all the classes on the element.

If you want to check for the existence of a specific class, use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass).

```
var hasJoy = myDiv.hasClass('joyous');
```

Comment: Think it's worth mentioning that these are jQuery methods.

Comment: Right, these are jQuery.  You could use DOM methods directly if you don't already have jQuery objects available.

Comment: this would work but i am looking to get the class of a specific DOM object not all of them

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
    var className = e.target.className;
    alert(className);
});
```

```css
b{
background-color:lightgreen;
padding:10px 20px;
margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b class='class-one'>Class One</b>
<b class='class-two'>Class-Two</b>
<b class='class-three'>Class-Three</b>
```